# How to LEFT JOIN the wp_terms, wp_term_relationships, wp_term_taxonomy and wp_termmeta tables in WordPress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

For reporting purposes and to flatten the data I want to join all the WordPress tables that contain information related to terms.

I really don't use join statements very much so I don't know how to do it. I'm guessing that it would look something like this:

```
SELECT wp_terms.term_id, wp_terms.name, wp_term.slug, wp_term_relationships.object_id, wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id, wp_term_taxonomy.term_id, wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy, wp_term_taxonomy.description, wp_term_taxonomy.parent.parent, wp_termmeta.term_id, wp_termmeta.meta_key, wp_termmeta.meta_value. 
FROM wp_terms, wp_term_relationships, wp_term_taxonomy, wp_termmeta
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON term_taxonomy_id
LEFT JOIN wp_termmeta on term_id;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you need to tell the query what are the matching keys `LEFT JOIN wp_termmeta on term_id = other_term_id` etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did was just fix your query. Check if this is what you need.

```
SELECT wp_terms.term_id, wp_terms.name, wp_term_relationships.object_id, wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id, wp_term_taxonomy.term_id, wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy, wp_term_taxonomy.description, wp_term_taxonomy.parent, wp_termmeta.term_id, wp_termmeta.meta_key, wp_termmeta.meta_value
FROM wp_terms
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
LEFT JOIN wp_termmeta on wp_termmeta.term_id = wp_terms.term_id
```